# Join ambiguous same value into select and on

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I got some problems with **INNER JOIN**.

Table **ref_vg_ou** :

```
id_vg | ref
  12     1
  13     1
  14     2
```

Table **vignette_ou** :

```
id_vg | ou_name | ou_info
  12     ezzaez   eaezaeae
  13      tbtrb    grtrr
  14      hyht      yhty
```

**mySQL request :**

```
SELECT id_vg, ou_name, ou_info
        FROM vignette_ou AS vg
        INNER JOIN ref_vg_ou AS ref
            ON vg.vg_id = ref.vg_id
        WHERE ref.ref = ?
```

My console return an error :

> 'id_vg' field list is ambiguous

I don't understand why my "id_vg" is ambiguous ? I tried with Alias, but I got a new error :

```
SELECT vg.id_vg, vg.ou_name, vg.ou_info
        FROM vignette_ou AS vg
        INNER JOIN ref_vg_ou AS ref
            ON vg.vg_id = ref.vg_id
        WHERE ref.ref = ?
```

Error :

> 'vg.vg_id' unknown on clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your sample table structure shows that you don't have a `vg_id` column, but `id_vg`.
- In case of queries involving multiple table, it is preferable to use name of the Table, or defined Alias (if any),  to refer respective column(s). You are getting "ambiguous" column error message, because you have `id_vg` column in both the tables. MySQL is not able to identify which one to pick (without proper table name or Alias reference given).
- Also, **note** that once you have defined the Alias on a table, you can only refer to its column(s) using that Alias.

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT vg.id_vg, vg.ou_name, vg.ou_info
FROM vignette_ou AS vg
INNER JOIN ref_vg_ou AS ref
  ON vg.id_vg = ref.id_vg
WHERE ref.ref = ?
```

Comment: OMG !!! I need to buy new eyes. Thank you very much too your help. I have to stay focus when I code sunday morning ;°).

Comment: @Renjus Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are joining on two identically named columns in your ON clause you could instead use the alternative JOIN syntax with **USING** and the matching column(s) for your JOIN conditition ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)). This would also remove the need for table aliases to identify to which table the `id_vg` in SELECT comes from.

So,

```
SELECT id_vg, ou_name, ou_info
FROM vignette_ou
INNER JOIN ref_vg_ou USING (id_vg)
WHERE ref = ?
```

will also work here.